# Pass props returned by login into props.history.push function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a React, express, mongo application that I am working on and I am wanting to get the pets for a specific user after they have logged in. I am not sure how I should retrieve the username from the logged in user and then pass it into my PetListing component. I have tried a few things, but I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.

**Login component:**

```js
    import React, {Component, useState} from 'react';
    const LoginForm = (props) => {
        const [state, setState] = useState({
            username: '',
            password: '',
        });
    
        const onSubmit =(event)=>{
            event.preventDefault();
            fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', {
                method:'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(state),
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                if(res.status === 200){
                    props.history.push('/pets');
                    state
                } else {
                    const error = new Error(res.error);
                    throw error;
                }
    
            })
            .catch(err=> {
                console.log(err);
                alert("Error when logging in.")
            })
    
            
        };
       const handleInputChange = (event) => {
            const {value, name} = event.target;
            setState((prevstate)=> ({
                ...prevstate,
                [name]:value
            }));
        };
```

**Pet listing component**

```js
    import React from 'react';
    
    
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export default class PetListing extends React.Component{
        state= {
            username : '',
            pets: []
        }
    
    
        componentDidMount(){
            axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/pets/${this.state.username}`)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res);
                console.log(res.data);
            })
        }
    
        render()
    {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.pets.map(tickets => <li>{pets.pet_id}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```js
<Nav className="justify-content-end">
              <Nav>
                <Link to={"/pets/{username}"} className="nav-link">
                  View your pets
                </Link>
              </Nav>
```

Comment: could you please show your login API or can tell what you're getting from the API response ?

Comment: Any state that needs to be accessed in more than one component needs to be lifted up the tree, then passed down as props. If a child needs to also change that state, also pass down a function to do so.

Comment: My login API returns a cookie if the user is successfully logged in, else it returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Route to `<Route path='/pets/:username' component={PetListingComponent} />`

And then you can assess the username in that component using `this.props.match.params.username`

I'm saying this from [here](https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-link/)

Comment: Will I need to change something within my Login component as I get errors about the line of code:`const onSubmit =(event)=>{
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(state),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200){
                props.history.push('/pets/:username');
                state
            } else {
`

Answer (score 0):

Solved through doing this:
Login

```
 .then(res => {
        if(res.status === 200){
            
            console.log(res);
            props.history.push(`/pets/${state.username}`);
           
        } else {
            const error = new Error(res.error);
            throw error;
        }

    })
```

petlist:

```
componentDidMount()
    
{
    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/pets/${this.props.match.params.username}`)
    .then((pets)=> {
        this.setState({pets: pet.data})
        
    })
}

render()
{
    var pets;
    if(this.state.pets!= null){
        //console.log(this.state.pets)
     tickets = this.state.pets.map(pet=> <div>{pet._id}</div>);
    }
    return(
        <div>
          <ul>{pets}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```